# The order of stdout and stderr in bash

Tags: bash, redirect

```
ls test.mp4  test.sh 1>/tmp/text  2>&1
cat   /tmp/text
ls: cannot access test.sh: No such file or directory
test.mp4
```

Why the result is not the following order?

```
test.mp4
ls: cannot access test.sh: No such file or directory
```

Maybe `1>/tmp/text` was executed first, and test.mp4 locate before test.sh.
Which result in the effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with bash. It simply reflects the way the C standard library I/O functions buffer output.

Here's a useful excerpt from `man setvbuf` on a Linux system (the explanation is mostly derived from the C and Posix standards, but I think it's easy to find and understand in this excerpt). The second paragraph is the explanation for the behaviour you see.

> The three types of buffering available are unbuffered, block buffered, and line buffered.  When an output stream is unbuffered, information appears on the destination file or terminal as soon as written; when it is block buffered many characters are saved up and written as a block; when it is line buffered characters are saved up until a newline is output or input is read from any stream attached to a terminal device (typically stdin).  The function fflush(3) may be used to force the block out early.  (See fclose(3).)
>
> Normally all files are block buffered.  If a stream refers to a terminal (as stdout normally does), it is line buffered.  The standard error stream stderr is always unbuffered by default.

So, to recap. `stdout` normally refers to the terminal and is therefore line-buffered, but you have redirected it to a file so it is block buffered. However, `stderr` is always unbuffered whether or not it has been redirected.

Consequently, anything printed to `stderr` appears immediately, while anything printed to `stdout` will be held until the buffer fills up (on Linux, normally 8kb).

Note that when `ls` detects that `stdout` is not a terminal, it sets the `-1` flag by default (one filename per line). Otherwise, it will set the `-x` flag by default (as many filenames as will fit on a line). That means that you will see the same inversion on a terminal without any redirecting at all:

```
$ ls good bad
ls: cannot access bad: No such file or directory
good
```

Answer (score 1):

stdout appears to be buffered and flushed at _exit.
stderr on the other hand, is a bit more urgent. I don't think bash waits until _exit to flush that out. If it is buffered at all.